# C program printing garbage values

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create an array and assign values to it. While I am able to assign values correctly, I am unable to retrieve those values and I have no idea why.

Here is a part of the code snippet.

```
  void *arr = (void *)(malloc(sizeof(void *) * 5));
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    *(int *)(arr+i) = initial[i];
    printf("Value of array: %d\n", *(int *)(arr+i));
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Pushing: %d\n", *(int *)(arr+i));
    DArray_push(result, (arr+i));
  }
```

The output of the program is

```
Value of array: 4
Value of array: 1
Value of array: 3
Value of array: 2
Value of array: 0
Pushing: 33751300
Pushing: 131841
Pushing: 515
Pushing: 2
Pushing: 0
```

Why is my program able to accept values correctly, but is printing out garbage values when I try to retrieve them later?

Comment: Add missing functions and stuff( DArray_push, initial, etc)

Comment: `void *arr = (void *)(malloc(sizeof(void *) * 5)` - you sure you should be using this as an integer array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pushing: 33751300 = 4 + 1 * 256 + 3 * 256 * 256 + 2 * 256 * 256 * 256
Pushing: 131841 = 1 + 3 * 256 + 2 * 256 * 256
Pushing: 515 = 3 + 2 * 256
Pushing: 2
Pushing: 0
```

That part is already wrong, but would on most 32 or 64 bit compilers still work: `sizeof(void *)`. Only because this this at least the size of an `int` on these platforms though.

```
*(int *)(arr+i)
```

This is the actual problem. This did not access the next integer, it accessed the next address addressable by a void pointer, which is typically a single byte. Accessing the next integer would had been equivalent to this:

```
*(int *)(arr + i*sizeof(int))
```

Or easier to read:

```
*( ((int *)arr) + i)
```

Remember, incrementing a pointer by an offset doesn't add to the raw memory address, but it depends on the pointer type.

Comment: Depends, undefined / forbidden in ANSI C. Allowed and well defined in GNU C.

Comment: Okay, so this works, but what confuses me is that if I was placing all my values at intervals of `*(int *)(arr + i)` versus `*(int *)(arr + i * sizeof(int)`, it should still work as long as I stay consistent right? Or is it that the value I am placing inside that memory block is of size int, therefore that's the maximum interval I can move by each time?

Comment: You have been incrementing the pointer by only a single byte. That may be consistent, but `int` is 4 bytes in size, so you were always partially overlapping the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Turn warnings on. `(arr+i)` is not defined (you cannot add to a void pointer and you do the cast only after this addition). You see undefined behavior.

You further allocate things the size of a pointer but treat it as `int` (more undefined behavior).

Why not write:

```
  int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = initial[i];
    printf("Value of array: %d\n", arr[i]);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Pushing: %d\n", arr[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Well, the way I've been told to define the data struct DArray, which *arr is a part of, is defined like so typedef struct DArray {
  int end;
  int max;
  size_t element_size;
  size_t expand_rate;
  void **contents;
} DArray;

Therefore, I can't use a single pointer to an array for a void array right? As far as I know, it needs to be a double pointer.

Comment: Also, I have -Wall enabled, which should show me all warnings, but I did not get a warning for this.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun You are dealing with a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem...re-think your question

Comment: "`contents` _is a pointer to an array with_ `end-1` _elements of size_ `element_size`". You don't need a double pointer. You can cast `void *arr= contents;` and address an element `n` as `*((char *)arr+(n*element_size))`.

Comment: Is the reason you've casted to a `(char *)` pointer, so you can add to the pointer and iterate over the array? Why not cast to any pointer like an `(int *)` pointer then? Is it because `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(char *)` are both 8 bytes?

Comment: The reason to cast to `(char *)` is that it tells the compiler that the size of each element pointed to is 1 (the `sizeof(char)`) so you can add in increments of 1, i.e. `element_size`. Pointer arithmatic is in items the size of the thing pointed to (and `void` has no size).

Answer (score 1):

The point here is the arithmetic of pointers. When we're adding a value by 1, it wouldn't be the same for different type pointers. So let's check an example:

```
(int  *)p + 1 // it's moving 4 bytes
(void *)p + 1 // it's moving 1 byte in my compiler, void * is a generic type
```

In your example we know we're working with integers, so we need to tell the compiler to convert the generic pointer to the appropriate type before we do any operations with.

Try to execute the following code to understand what I'm gonna talking about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int initial[] = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104};
    void *arr = (void *)(malloc(sizeof(void *) * 5));
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%p\t%p\n", arr + i, ((int *)arr) + i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *(((int *)arr)+i) = initial[i];
        printf("Value of array: %d\n", *(((int *)arr)+i));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Pushing: %d\n", *(((int *)arr)+i));
    }
}
```

I found some resources to help:

https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

https://www.viva64.com/en/t/0005/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you don't reset your arr pointer. Thus in your second loop you actually print the values after the initial array.

You need to create a variable to traverse your array.

```
void *p = arr;
```

And then use it to traverse the array. And again before the second loop.

Moreover, do not cast the return value of a malloc function call (even when you are casting it to a void pointer which is the actual return type of malloc).

EDIT: you actually don't change the value of arr. My bad.

Comment: He does not need to reset the pointer. He uses the expression `(arr+i)` so `arr` is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the thing with casting malloc to void and using sizeof void is totally pointeless.

Assuming `initial[]`is another array, the fix would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int initial[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

int main()
{
    //allocate memory for 5 integers
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

    //loop over and copy from inital to arr
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = initial[i];
        printf("Value of array: %d\n", arr[i]);
    }

  //pointer to first element of arr
  int* arrPointer = arr;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Pushing: %d\n", *arrPointer);
    //DArray_push(result, (*arrPointer));
    //increment the arrPointer
    arrPointer++;
  }

  //reset pointer if needed later...
  arrPointer = arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: he doesn't use `sizeof(void)` but `sizeof(void *) ` which is well defined.

Comment: Saied, add a `*` and I'll upvote for that first line alone.

Comment: @usr2564301oooppps

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean *that* line (and are you sure it is correct?). I mean the `sizeof void` in the very first paragraph that Paul also remarks upon.

Comment: @usr2564301 hmmm I dont know...it looks fine to me